# Array bidimensional en función de text area

Tags: php, php7

tengo un text area en el que el usuario almacena la información de esta forma:

```
hello=>hola
bye=>Adios
Good Morning=> Buenos días.
```

Me gustaría organizarlo en un array clave valor de esta forma:

```
$languages=[
['hello']=>'hola',
['bye']=>'adios',
['good morning']=>'Buenos días',


]
```

Con esta pequeña función consigo crear un elemento del array por cada línea, pero no es lo que necesito.

```
 $new_array = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $target)));
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partimos de la base de que tienes mal puesta la sintaxis de lo que pides, pues esto no existe en PHP, da error:

```
$languages=[
    ['hello'] => 'hola',
    ['bye'] => 'adios',
    ['good morning'] => 'Buenos días',
];
```

Así que yo he desarrollado mi respuesta más bien sobre este supuesto array:

```
$languages=[
    ['hello'=>'hola'],
    ['bye'=>'adios'],
    ['good morning'=>'Buenos días']
];
```

Siendo así, esta es mi propuesta de solución:

```php
<?php
$target = '
hello=>hola
bye=>Adios
Good Morning=> Buenos días.
';

$languages = [];
foreach (preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $target) as $line) {
    if ($line !== '') {
        $temp = explode("=>", $line);
        array_push($languages, [$temp[0] => $temp[1]]);
    }
}

print_r($languages);
```

**Explicación:**

Primero creamos una variable de array para almacenar el posible resultado esperado:

```php
$languages = [];
```

Después dividimos el string `target` en líneas con [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) pasándole los posibles saltos de linea a encontrar con una expresión regular, que en este caso es:

```php
((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))
```

Eso nos creará las lineas una a una, almacenadas en la variable $line, y dentro de ese bucle `foreach` vamos a poder realizar lo siguiente con ella.

De saque evitamos las líneas en blanco, por si acaso, con el condicional siguiente:

```php
    if ($line !== '') {
```

y si la línea no está en blanco entonces la tratamos tal como esperamos encontrarla, dividiendola en una nueva variable de array denominada $temp que será el resultado de dividir la línea mediante el delimitador `=>`, creando un array de dos elementos, el [0] y el [1], correspondientes a cada lado del delimitador. Todo esto mediante esta instrucción:

```php
$temp = explode("=>", $line);
```

Luego ya pasamos a agregar un nuevo elemento de array en el formato deseado, mediante `array_push`:

```php
array_push($languages, [$temp[0] => $temp[1]]);
```

aunque tambien podriamos haberlo hecho así:

```php
$languages[] = [$temp[0] => $temp[1]];
```

Y ya, cuando se terminan todos estos ciclos, tendremos la variable `$languages` con todos los elementos y podremos visualizarla en el formato deseado mediante:

```php
print_r($languages);
```

lo cual a mi me muestra esto:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hello] => hola
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bye] => Adios
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Good Morning] =>  Buenos días.
        )

)
```

que si lo comparo con esto:

```
$languages=[
    ['hello'] => 'hola',
    ['bye'] => 'adios',
    ['good morning'] => 'Buenos días',
];
print_r($languages);
```

Por último, en el supuesto que el array final se quisiera así (creo que es mejor este formato para su posterior acceso por clave):

```php
$languages=[
    'hello'=>'hola',
    'bye'=>'adios',
    'good morning'=>'Buenos días'
];
```

simplemente se tendría que sustituir esta línea:

```php
array_push($languages, [$temp[0] => $temp[1]]);
```

por esta otra:

```php
$new_array[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, un millón de gracias!

Comment: @user1798310 Ahora si, acabo de terminar la redacción completa. Mírate el supuesto final pues creo que te conviene más un formato de array de ese modo para luego acceder mediante $languages['hello'] en lugar de $languages[0]['hello'], pero bueno, eso ya es cosa tuya decidirlo, tan solo lo comento por si acaso.  Y sino tambien puedes modificarlo a tu gusto, ahora ya sabes como jugar con ello.